# Save images with plt.savefig but the images are all white

Tags: python, image, save

I use matplotlib to show the images and save them.

But the image I saved are all blank

This is the code i use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2 
path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/0_180_direction_indicator/*.jpg'
for deg in Result.values[:,1:4]:
    #print(deg)
    for img in glob.glob(path):
        if int(img[-13:-10])== int(deg[2]):
            print(deg[1])
            print(str(deg[2])[0:5]+'_deg')
            IMG_SIZE = 100
            img_array = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
            plt.imshow(new_array)
            plt.show()  
            plt.savefig('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/indicator_result/'+str(deg[1])+str(deg[2])[0:5]+'_deg'+'.jpg')
```

But the images I saved are all white...
How to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

plt.savefig saves the current image. If you call plt.show() before saving it, it will not work.

Change

```
plt.imshow(new_array)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/indicator_result/'+str(deg[1])+str(deg[2])[0:5]+'_deg'+'.jpg')
```

to

```
plt.imshow(new_array)
plt.savefig(..)
plt.show()
```